# Scalars leaked: -2 Scalars leaked: 2 warning in a multi threaded perl script

Tags: multithreading, perl, memory, centos, thread-safety

During the end of my multi threaded perl script, I get error like below. The number changes from time to time.

```
Scalars leaked: -2 
Scalars leaked:2
```

What could be the cause of this problem? Are they just warnings?

I have created my threads in the following way:

```
    our $threads1=3;
    our $threads2=3;

    for(my $i = 0; $i<$threads1; $i++)
    {
        $threadpool1[$i] = threads->create( \&sub1, $arg1, $arg2 , $arg2, $threads1, $threads2);
    }


    #Add work to queue1
    foreach my $work (keys %{$workobj})
    {
        $queue1->enqueue( $work );
    }

    for(my $i = 0; $i<$threads2; $i++)
    {
        $threadpool2[$i] = threads->create( \&sub2, $arg1 , $arg2);
    }

    #Wait until worker threads complete the work
    $_->join for @threadpool1;
    $_->join for @threadpool2;

    sub sub1($arg1, $arg2 , $arg2, $threads1, $threads2)
    {
        while($queue1->dequeue)
        {
              #do some work
              #send work to queue 2
              $queue2->enqueue(work);
              $queue1->enqueue(undef x threads1);
        }
        # if all work has been sent to second queue, send undef to second set of threads
        $queue1->enqueue(undef x $threads2);
        return;
    }

    sub sub1($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        while($queue2->dequeue)
        {
              #do some work
        }
        return;
    }
```

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Comment: `use diagnostics;`

Comment: I seriously doubt the code you presented gives the issue you describe. (It doesn't even run, for starters.) /// I suspect an XS-based module that isn't thread-safe. /// I've had problems passing arguments to threads before, so you might want to try replacing `\&sub1, $arg1, $arg2 , $arg2, $THREADS1, $THREADS2` with `sub { sub1($arg1, $arg2 , $arg2, $THREADS1, $THREADS2) }` /// Could also try using Thread::Queue::Any instead of Thread::Queue.

Comment: What's with using `our` instead of `my`???

Comment: `for(my $i = 0; $i<$var; $i++)` is better written `for my $i (0..$var-1)`

Comment: @ikegami I wanted to share the `$THREADS1` to all the  threads. to send `undef` to the number of `$THREADS1` when all the work items are completed.

Comment: `our` doesn't help you do that

Comment: I have added more details to my question as how I am handling the stopping of threads...